# how to create/update item in dynamo db?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I tried a sample code ( see below) , to create new items in dynamo db . based on the docs for dynamodb and boto3, the sample code adds the item in dynamodb in batch, but just from the code , it looks like put item is being called in each iteration of the for loop below. any thoughts, also , i understand for updating item, there is no batch operation , we have to call update item one at a time?

```
import boto3
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('my-table')

with table.batch_writer() as writer:
    for item in somelist:
        writer.put_item(Item=item)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you called the `put_item()` method on the `writer` object. This `writer` object is a batch writer - it is a *wrapper* of the original table object. This wrapper doesn't perform every `put_item()` request individually!  Instead,

- As its name suggests, the batch writer collects **batches** of up to 25 writes in memory, and only on the 25th call, it sends all 25 writes as one DynamoDB `BatchWriteItem` request.
- Then, at the end of the loop, the `writer` object is destroyed when the the `with` block ends, and this sends the final partial batch as one last `BatchWriteItem` request.

As you can see, Python made efficient writing using batches very transparent and easy.

Comment: thanks. on the same note, note sure why there is not a similar concept for bulk update, or is there?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for as "bulk update". The batch writer is pretty good for relatively small bulk updates. But for larger bulks, you probably want to do multiple writes in parallel, from the same client and even from multiple client machines in parallel. Not all of this logic makes sense to have in the general-purpose library and needs some cooperation from the application (where does the application get the data to upload? is the application parallelized between multiple machines? etc.).

Comment: Or, by "bulk update" did you mean in the sense of UpdateItem as opposed to PutItem? If that's your question then, no - unfortunately that's not available. BatchWriteItem can only overwrite entire items - it can't update pieces of items.

Comment: thanks again. one last follow up question - instead of trying to update the item, if i use PutItem for an existing id, that should overwrite the existing item with the dynamo, right? if that's the case , i can use this to update the item, sort of a work around but i will be able to use the bulk create for both creating new item and updating exist item.

Answer (score 2):

The boto3 batch writer buffers internally and sends each batch automatically. It’s like magic.